# Bluetooth continuously write to characteristic

Tags: android, bluetooth, xamarin.android

I have 2 Android applications. One of them advertises a UUID via bluetooth, and provides write characteristics. The other one scans for a device advertising this UUID, connects to it, and then writes to its 2 characteristics.

Basically, I need the device/app that is advertising the UUID (I'll call it the "server app" now) to always know when the other device/app is present, as well as its UUID that I am writing to. I have to have 2 write characteristics for the UUID, because it's too long to fit into 1, so I write the first half of the UUID in the first characteristic, and the second half in the second characteristic.

So the flow of the apps are as such:

1. The "server app" advertises a UUID
2. The other app scans for the advertising UUID
3. The devices come within Bluetooth range
4. The app that is scanning finds the advertising UUID, and connects to the device.
5. The app then writes its own UUID to the 2 characteristics.
6. The "server app" receives the UUID and displays it on the screen.
7. The app continuously writes its UUID to the 2 characteristics while within Bluetooth range, even after being separated out of range and then brought back within range.

What I have working is the first 6 steps. I can't get step 7 to work.

The problem that I have, is after the UUID is written to the 2 characteristics, it won't write to it anymore. So the "server app" won't know that the other device/app is present anymore or not. I have to terminate the app (that does the scanning) and restart it so that it can connect to the other device/app and write to the characteristics again.

I need to continuously write to the characteristics when they are near each other (with some delay in between is fine). Even after the devices are separated in distance greater than the Bluetooth range, and then brought back together. I wrote these apps in Xamarin, but I think it applies to Android in general. Here is my code for the app that advertises the UUID:

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    private static Java.Util.UUID AdvertiseUUID = Java.Util.UUID.FromString("59ed0f55-e984-4fc2-9403-b1e64269ec5e");
    private static Java.Util.UUID ServiceUUID = Java.Util.UUID.FromString("89c9a1f2-5c38-492d-b8e9-67830268682e");
    private static Java.Util.UUID WriteCharacteristic1UUID = Java.Util.UUID.FromString("92515af8-8d70-40a7-b5b1-5a5bd624e5a0");
    private static Java.Util.UUID WriteCharacteristic2UUID = Java.Util.UUID.FromString("71d640cb-bb78-45bd-ae26-614fead76efe");

    BluetoothLeAdvertiser advertiser;
    BluetoothGattServer gattServer;
    BluetoothGattService service;
    MyAdvertiseCallback callback = new MyAdvertiseCallback();

    private static string writeText1;
    private static string writeText2;

    private static List<PassengerDevice> passengerDevices = new List<PassengerDevice>();

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        LoadApplication(new App());

        AndroidBluetoothServer();
    }

    private async Task AndroidBluetoothServer()
    {
        try
        {
            CreateGattServer();

            advertiser = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter.BluetoothLeAdvertiser;

            var advertiseBuilder = new AdvertiseSettings.Builder();
            var parameters = advertiseBuilder.SetConnectable(true)
                                             .SetAdvertiseMode(AdvertiseMode.LowLatency)
                                             .SetTxPowerLevel(AdvertiseTx.PowerHigh)
                                             .Build();

            AdvertiseData data = (new AdvertiseData.Builder()).AddServiceUuid(new ParcelUuid(AdvertiseUUID)).Build();
            advertiser.StartAdvertising(parameters, data, callback);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
    }

    private void CreateGattServer()
    {
        service = new BluetoothGattService(ServiceUUID, GattServiceType.Primary);

        BluetoothGattCharacteristic writeCharacteristic1 = new BluetoothGattCharacteristic(WriteCharacteristic1UUID, GattProperty.WriteNoResponse, GattPermission.Write);
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic writeCharacteristic2 = new BluetoothGattCharacteristic(WriteCharacteristic2UUID, GattProperty.WriteNoResponse, GattPermission.Write);

        service.AddCharacteristic(writeCharacteristic1);
        service.AddCharacteristic(writeCharacteristic2);

        var bluetoothManager = GetSystemService(BluetoothService) as BluetoothManager;
        gattServer = bluetoothManager.OpenGattServer(BaseContext, new MyGattServerCallback());
        gattServer.AddService(service);
    }

    public class MyGattServerCallback : BluetoothGattServerCallback
    {
        public override void OnCharacteristicWriteRequest(BluetoothDevice device, int requestId, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, bool preparedWrite, bool responseNeeded, int offset, byte[] value)
        {
            base.OnCharacteristicWriteRequest(device, requestId, characteristic, preparedWrite, responseNeeded, offset, value);

            var str = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(value);

            var passengerDevice = passengerDevices.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Address == device.Address);

            if(passengerDevice != null)
            {
                if (characteristic.Uuid == WriteCharacteristic1UUID)
                {
                    passengerDevice.Text1 = str;
                }
                else if (characteristic.Uuid == WriteCharacteristic2UUID)
                {
                    passengerDevice.Text2 = str;
                    passengerDevice.RecievedTimestamp = DateTime.Now;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var newDevice = new PassengerDevice();
                newDevice.Address = device.Address;

                if (characteristic.Uuid == WriteCharacteristic1UUID)
                {
                    newDevice.Text1 = str;
                }
                else if (characteristic.Uuid == WriteCharacteristic2UUID)
                {
                    newDevice.Text2 = str;
                }

                passengerDevices.Add(newDevice);
            }

            App2.Class1.SetText(passengerDevices);
        }
    }

    public class MyAdvertiseCallback : AdvertiseCallback
    {
        public override void OnStartFailure([GeneratedEnum] AdvertiseFailure errorCode)
        {
            base.OnStartFailure(errorCode);
        }

        public override void OnStartSuccess(AdvertiseSettings settingsInEffect)
        {
            base.OnStartSuccess(settingsInEffect);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnDestroy()
    {
        try
        {
            if(advertiser != null)
            {
                advertiser.StopAdvertising(callback);
                advertiser.Dispose();
                advertiser = null;
            }

            if (service != null)
            {
                service.Dispose();
                service = null;
            }

            if (gattServer != null)
            {
                gattServer.Close();
                gattServer.Dispose();
                gattServer = null;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            base.OnDestroy();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my code for the app that scans for the UUID and writes to the characteristics:

```
public class AndroidBluetooth
{
    private static Java.Util.UUID AdvertiseUUID = Java.Util.UUID.FromString("59ed0f55-e984-4fc2-9403-b1e64269ec5e");
    private static Java.Util.UUID ServiceUUID = Java.Util.UUID.FromString("89c9a1f2-5c38-492d-b8e9-67830268682e");
    private static Java.Util.UUID WriteCharacteristic1UUID = Java.Util.UUID.FromString("92515af8-8d70-40a7-b5b1-5a5bd624e5a0");
    private static Java.Util.UUID WriteCharacteristic2UUID = Java.Util.UUID.FromString("71d640cb-bb78-45bd-ae26-614fead76efe");

    private ScanCallback _scanCallback;
    private ScanSettings _scanSettings;
    private ScanFilter _scanFilter;
    private MyBluetoothGattCallback _gattCallback;
    private static ParcelUuid _parcelUuid;

    public static bool IsStarted { get; private set; }

    public void StartAndroidBluetoothClient()
    {
        IsStarted = true;

        _parcelUuid = new ParcelUuid(AdvertiseUUID);

        _gattCallback = new MyBluetoothGattCallback();

        _scanCallback = new MyScanCallback() { GattCallback = _gattCallback };

        _scanFilter = new ScanFilter.Builder().SetServiceUuid(new ParcelUuid(AdvertiseUUID))
                                              .Build();

        _scanSettings = new ScanSettings.Builder().SetScanMode(Android.Bluetooth.LE.ScanMode.LowLatency)
                                                  .Build();

        BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter.BluetoothLeScanner.StartScan(new List<ScanFilter>() { _scanFilter }, _scanSettings, _scanCallback);
    }

    public class MyScanCallback : ScanCallback
    {
        public MyBluetoothGattCallback GattCallback { get; set; }

        public override void OnScanResult([GeneratedEnum] ScanCallbackType callbackType, ScanResult result)
        {
            base.OnScanResult(callbackType, result);

            result.Device.ConnectGatt(Android.App.Application.Context, true, GattCallback);
        }

        public override void OnScanFailed([GeneratedEnum] ScanFailure errorCode)
        {
            base.OnScanFailed(errorCode);
        }
    }

    public class MyBluetoothGattCallback : BluetoothGattCallback
    {
        public BluetoothGatt Gatt { get; set; }

        public override void OnConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, [GeneratedEnum] GattStatus status, [GeneratedEnum] ProfileState newState)
        {
            base.OnConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);

            // It is Success the first time, but then never again until I kill the app and restart it
            if (status == GattStatus.Success)
            {
                Gatt = gatt;
                gatt.DiscoverServices();
            }
        }

        public override void OnServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, [GeneratedEnum] GattStatus status)
        {
            base.OnServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);

            if (status == GattStatus.Success)
            {
                var service = gatt.GetService(ServiceUUID);
                if (service != null)
                {
                    var wc1 = service.GetCharacteristic(WriteCharacteristic1UUID);

                    if (wc1 != null)
                    {
                        wc1.SetValue("71d640cb-bb78-45bd");
                        gatt.WriteCharacteristic(wc1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public override void OnCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, [GeneratedEnum] GattStatus status)
        {
            base.OnCharacteristicWrite(gatt, characteristic, status);

            if (status != GattStatus.Success)
            {
                // try again
                if (characteristic.Uuid.Equals(WriteCharacteristic1UUID))
                {
                    var service = gatt.GetService(ServiceUUID);
                    var wc1 = service.GetCharacteristic(WriteCharacteristic1UUID);
                    if (wc1 != null)
                    {
                        wc1.SetValue("71d640cb-bb78-45bd");
                        gatt.WriteCharacteristic(wc1);
                    }
                }
                else if (characteristic.Uuid.Equals(WriteCharacteristic2UUID))
                {
                    var service = gatt.GetService(ServiceUUID);
                    var wc2 = service.GetCharacteristic(WriteCharacteristic2UUID);
                    if (wc2 != null)
                    {
                        wc2.SetValue("-ae26-614fead76efe");
                        gatt.WriteCharacteristic(wc2);
                    }
                }

                return;
            }

            if (characteristic.Uuid.Equals(WriteCharacteristic1UUID))
            {
                // now send the second text
                var service = gatt.GetService(ServiceUUID);
                var wc2 = service.GetCharacteristic(WriteCharacteristic2UUID);
                if (wc2 != null)
                {
                    wc2.SetValue("-ae26-614fead76efe");
                    gatt.WriteCharacteristic(wc2);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        if(_gattCallback.Gatt != null)
        {
            // Some devices (or Android versions) will disconnect automatically when the app closes, but some won't and then you'll have to power off the phone to make sure the hardware is disconnected, and you won't be able to connect again until you do.
            _gattCallback.Gatt.Close();
            _gattCallback.Gatt.Disconnect();
            _gattCallback.Gatt = null;
        }

        IsStarted = false;
    }
}
```

I write to the 2 characteristics, one after the other, and then it never writes to them again until I kill and restart the app...how can I make it continuously write to the characteristics when the devices are within range?

Comment: what is the return value of gatt.WriteCharacteristic()? maybe the gatt client still expects an response from the write operation, even though you configured the characteristic as WriteWithoutResposne?

Comment: I'm not at my office right now so I can't check, but I'm sure it returns `true` because I can visually see the value of what I'm writing on the other device as I am displaying it on the screen (`71d640cb-bb78-45bd` and `-ae26-614fead76efe`)

Comment: hm, does it also return true on the second write (that one which don't work)? What might fix your issue is checking if the the write requires a response (in that case, requiresResponse property would be true) and send a response with gattServer.SendResponse(...) if required. Also your issue might come from sending the writes to fast, you could try to insert a Task.Delay between the operations

Comment: Both writes work. My issue is that if the devices are separated after doing the writes (and are thus disconnected), and then brought back together, it can't connect and do the writes anymore. I basically need the device/app that is advertising the UUID to always know when the other device/app is present, as well as its UUID that I am writing to.

Comment: I realized the way I worded my question was confusing, so I rewrote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some big question there, but I read through it all and I'll give you some pointers on where to go. For a full app most of those stuff would be IMHO in separate classes, taking care of just 1 responsibility, but I'll try my best:

- " I need the (...) "server app" (...) to always know when the other device/app is present,"

for that you can/should use callback from `BluetoothGattServerCallback.onConnectionStateChange()` . With that you can know when a device connects and disconnects without needing this convoluted "always write" logic.

- from what I understood on the client app you want:

  while(true) {
     while(not found) {
         scan()
     }
     connect()
     while(is connected) {
       write characteristic 1
       write characteristic 2
     }
  }

but from your code it seems you're missing the `while` parts. You're certainly missing inside `OnCharacteristicWrite` the part to keep repeating. Something like this:

```
        // if I just wrote the first
        if (characteristic.Uuid.Equals(WriteCharacteristic1UUID))
        {
            // write the sencond
            var service = gatt.GetService(ServiceUUID);
            var wc2 = service.GetCharacteristic(WriteCharacteristic2UUID);
            if (wc2 != null)
            {
                wc2.SetValue("-ae26-614fead76efe");
                gatt.WriteCharacteristic(wc2);
            }
        }
        // if we just wrote the second
        else if (characteristic.Uuid.Equals(WriteCharacteristic2UUID))
        {
            //write the 1st again
            ... insert here code that writes the 1st characteristic
        }
```

It seems to it's missing some disconnection handling code. This should goinside the `OnConnectionStateChange`.

You have to do something like this:

```
 if (status != GattStatus.Success || newState != CONNECTED)
 {
     // we're not connected, close the gatt
     try{  gatt.disconnect() } catch(exception) { } 
     gatt.close()
 }
 else
 {
      Gatt = gatt;
      gatt.DiscoverServices();
 }
```

Android have some limitations on this gatt, so it's very important to disconnect and close it, or else you'll run into some system limitations.

I've never used this auto-connect option `true`, but it seems to me that you never stopped scanning. That means that you'll keep receiving callbacks in `OnScanResult`, so you keep asking to connect again and again.

You should certainly make some flag that device is already found and there's no need to connect again. Like:

```
onScanResul(...
  if(!connectedOrConnectin) {
       connectedOrConnectin = true
       -> connect
       // make sure to clear the flag after disconnection.
  }
```

Also, you might want to not use the "auto-connect" flag to True (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37071781). It seems that you will get a much faster connection if trying to connect by the other method.

I hope it helps.